# How to change text justification in Matplotlib labels?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have made a graph in Matplotlib and want to change the justification of my rotated y-axis label.

In this code example, the text "This is an example plot" should be justified left.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
figure, axes = plt.subplots()
axes.plot([0, 1], [0, 1])
axes.set_ylabel('This is an\nexample plot', rotation=0)
axes.yaxis.set_label_coords(0.1, 0.9)
plt.show()
```

[image: plot figure with a label with centered text]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Matplotlib text commands, such as for labels and annotations, support a number of keyword arguments that affect alignment, orientation, spacing, font, etc. The full [list of text properties](https://matplotlib.org/users/text_props.html) can be found in the documentation. In the above example

```
axes.set_ylabel('This is an\nexample plot', rotation=0, horizontalalignment='left')
```

would do the trick.

As noted in the other answer, this particular example is an abuse of the y-axis label. But the general principle is the same for all kinds of Matplotlib labels.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't manipulate the ylabel this way. Instead just put some text at the location you want.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.offsetbox import AnchoredText
    
figure, axes = plt.subplots()
axes.plot([0, 1], [0, 1])
    
axes.add_artist(AnchoredText('This is an\nexample plot', "upper left", frameon=False))
    
plt.show()
```

[image: plot with text anchored in top left corner]